# Nodejs Difficulty using eval inside class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble using eval in my js file (class).

When I develop a code globally it works (Ex 1).

Now when I use eval inside the class it doesn't work (Ex 2)

**Code Ex 1** ->

```
var s = "function teste() {console.log('testando')}"
eval(s)

this.teste();
```

**Code Ex 2 -> **

```
class Oi {

  constructor() {
    this.s = ""
    this.t = ""
  }
  
  run(){
    this.s = "function teste() {console.log('testando')}"
    eval(this.s)
    
    this.teste();
  }
}

let o = new Oi();
o.run();
```

Comment: `str = "this.teste = function () {console.log('testando')}";` then `eval(str);` (with your current code, `teste` is local to the `run` function, not a method of the `Oi` class)

Comment: Why are you even using `eval()` for this.  `eval()` should not be used for regular code like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function in window scope.

```js
run(){
    this.s = "function teste() {console.log('testando')}"
    eval(this.s)
    
    window.teste();
  }
```